# Error message when using UDF and javascript - The project ____ has not enabled BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery console I created a UDF function (language js) and now trying to call it from a saved query. I tried referencing the UDF with projectID.dataset.UDF_Name (same as I am using the for referencing vies/tables). When I click Run in UI I got an error:

"The project XXX has not enabled BigQuery"

I checked the BigQuery API and it says enabled.

When I only used dataset.UDF_Name for reference the query worked but I can save it as view getting another error: Bad routine reference "dataset.UDF_Name()"; routine references in standard SQL views require explicit project IDs

So clearly, the right approach is to use the projectID.dataset.UDF_Name() format but I can't figure out how to get rid of the "The project XXX has not enabled BigQuery"  error.

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Is this looks like a bug, please use the BigQuery issue tracker, and make sure to mention your specific projects and datasets

Comment: Double check the name of the project shown at the top of the BigQuery UI. Based on the error messages, it sounds like you have a different project selected than the one you expect.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I did check the project name at the top of the https://console.cloud.google.com and the correct project is selected.  I am referencing the function with ProjectId.dataset-name.function().  I also tried  ProjectName.data-set.function() but getting '"Function not found".

Comment: @FelipeHoffa which group I should use for the issue -> https://prnt.sc/p4aipo ? Thanks

Comment: BigQuery (the first one)